# tesseract test xamarin bad output xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, ocr, tesseract

I set up everything about `tesseract` in my android app. When I scan text on my PC it returns me perfect result but when text is handwritten or scan document it return me very bad results. So where is problem or I should change something about image contrast or ... 
I tried many times but nothing

```
 String recognizedText = "???";   
 TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
 baseApi.Init(absolutePath, "eng");              
 baseApi.SetImage(image);
 recognizedText = baseApi.UTF8Text;

 OCR_textView.Text = "OCR :" + recognizedText;
```

Comment: Are the images you're scanning of similar resolution?

Comment: resolution ? what

Comment: The number of pixels in width and height per character. For example, if one image has a total of 200 pixels for one letter and the other has 50 (just random numbers), the second has a lower resolution and may be harder for OCR to read correctly.